# Mockito a void method

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

How do I write a mockito test for the below method? `IntReqDecorate.decorate` adds an Id to a call.

```
public class IntVisitor implements Visitor {

    private final IntReqDecorator intReqDecorator;

    public InternalCallVisitor() {
        this.intReqDecorator = new IntReqDecorator();
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(Call call) {
        intReqDecorator.decorate(call);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a bit of a bind here. Your `IntVisitor` class is very tightly coupled to the concrete class `IntReqDecorator`. And the `apply` method is defined, verbatim, to do the same thing as `intReqDecorator.decorate`. So without changing any of the signatures, the best you can possibly do is write the same test you did for `decorate` but over again.

Now, what you probably *should* do with this code is break that dependency. First, your constructor concretely builds an `IntReqDecorator` the moment it's constructed. You can still do that as a handy default, but you should provide a way for the caller to specify the decorator they wish to use. We can do that by overloading the constructor.

```
public InternalCallVisitor() {
  this(new IntReqDecorator());
}

public InternalCallVisitor(IntReqDecorator intReqDecorator) {
  this.intReqDecorator = intReqDecorator;
}
```

Now this alone is enough firepower for us to write a good test. We can mock `IntReqDecorator` and use the one-argument constructor in tests.

But I would go even further. You only ever use one method from `IntReqDecorator`, namely `decorate`. But since it's a concrete class, it probably has other methods that we don't really need here. So in an effort to follow [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), it may be a good idea to create an interface `IntReqDecoratorLike` (choose a better name for your use case) that has just that one method, and then have `IntReqDecorator` *implement* that interface.

Then your constructor takes a `IntReqDecoratorLike` that is capable of doing *only* exactly what we need it to. The great thing about this is that you barely even have to mock anything to test it. You could theoretically just write a new (ordinary) class that implements `IntReqDecoratorLike` and use that in tests. We'll probably still use the mocking framework, since it does provide good error messages and built-in validation, but the alternative is there in principle.

As a very broad general rule, when you find yourself scratching your head and saying "This code looks difficult to test", you should take a step back. Because oftentimes, you can make a change to the API that not only makes testing easier but also makes the code more ergonomic to use down the road.

Comment: I suppose you meant `this(new IntReqDecorator());` instead of `super(new IntReqDecorator());`?